# How to handle Spring boot job while running in multiple instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a spring boot application with simple trigger Job running in every 5 minutes. The Job will trigger when a file uploaded and its status is not processed.
We deployed this application in an elastic beanstalk environment with minimum 2 instances.
From both instances job will trigger in every 5 minutes.
So this two instances are processing same file at the same time. It will create duplicate records and the same file processed in multiple times.

We need to handle this Job processing issue. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get around this?

Comment: You need to enable the DB support of the Spring Scheduler. See section 4 of this page: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule

Answer (score 0):

You need to acquire a distributed lock(e.g. by Redisson) before processing your biz logic. See [doc](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/8.-Distributed-locks-and-synchronizers)

Comment: Our database is PostgreSQL

Comment: Or [dynamodb lock client](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-dynamodb-lock-client).

Comment: The key is lock which can be implemented based on DB